# Jekyll - Changing the page URL sitewide

Tags: html, hyperlink, jekyll

For SEO Reasons, I use the permalink option on all of my pages, so they are going to be generated in separate directories. But is there a way to handle the links in a central DB, so I can change the page URL and all links at the same time?

Just for example, I have the page `video.html`. It uses the option `permalink: /video/`, so the page is generated to `/video/index.html`.

On other pages I currently use the default HTML `<a href="/video/">...</a>` Tag to link to the page. But now I want to use the path of the Page to `/my_video/` on the whole site.

Is there another way of linking or is it possible to have a little db with URL- Schemes, so I have a central point, where I can change to link path and the permalink?

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize your link in an include file.

**_includes/links.md**

```
[video]: /video/
```

Now you can include this file in any markdown post or page and reference links like this.

```
[My video page][video]
```